# React/Nextjs with GraphQL: Posting data to backend (Spring) getting null object

Tags: typescript, graphql, next.js

I'm attempting to send data from my front-end (Nextjs) using a GraphQL Mutation to my backend (Java Spring). My issue is that when I call the Mutation from the GraphQL playground, in my backend, I got an object with null properties. Here is some bribes of the codes:

My Mutation definition:

```
export const SystemMutation = mutationType({
    definition(t) {
        t.field("addSystem",{
            type: System,
            args: {
                input: arg({
                    type: SystemInput
                })
            },
            async resolve(_parent, args, _context) {
                return await createSystem(args.input);
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Here is the function to call the backend to store the data.

```
export const createSystem = async (system) => {
    const res = await axios.post(`${server}/api/system/add`, system);
    return res.data;
}
```

And last the Spring controller that should receive the data in which when I debug the system variable, I got an object with null value in all attributes.

```
@PostMapping("/add")
    public ResponseEntity<?> add(@Validated(SystemDto.Create.class) @ModelAttribute SystemDto system,
                                 BindingResult result) {
        return this.systemService.createSystem(system, result);
    }
```

If I console.log the parameter "system" in the front-end, I got the data I wanna send. But when I send it in the backend I got a null object.

Do I miss something there?

Thanks for your lights guys.

Comment: `console.log(args.input)`? how called (query+variables) ?

Comment: Here is how I did call the mutation `mutation AddSystem($input: SystemInput!) {
  addSystem(input: $input){
    id,
    sysName,
    sysUri
  }
  }`
with `{
  "input": {
    "sysName": "data",
    "sysUri": "/test"
  }
}` as variable and here is the console.log of (args.input) `{ sysName: 'data', sysUri: '/test' }`. Seems like the data is good but somewhere before arriving to the backend, these data become null

Comment: if data logged properly - end of graphql [transport] role, it's ok on backend, on resolver

Comment: On my backend, if I call it via postman, the data pass throw like a charm though.